# How to close table in Jtable while openin another frame

Tags: jtable, frame

When I open another frame I know how to close this frame. What I should write when I want to close table made in Jtable?

That way I close one frame and open another:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new Name of frame().setVisible(true);  
                    Name of closing frame.this.dispose();
                  }
```

What should I write here?.this.dispose(); to close the Jtable frame?

The way I create table in JTable:

```
table qui=new table();
    qui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    qui.setVisible(true);
    qui.setSize(6000,2000);
    qui.setTitle("Table");
```

Do you have any ideas?
I can add that table or qui does not work.